# Localhost and 127.0.0.1 both refused to connect (may have resulted from trying to update ssl)

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp, localhost

I was trying to update SSL certificate for my website, but accidentally updated it incorrectly, leading to some issues restarting WAMPP server, and eventually lead to unsuccessful connection to localhost and 127.0.0.1.

What I was supposed to do:

- Make a copy of `cert.pem`, rename it to `server.crt` and paste it to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt`
- Make a copy of `privkey.pem`, rename it to `server.key` and paste it to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key`

What I did instead:

- Directly moved `cert.pem` file to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt` and rename it to `server.crt`, so the original file is gone from the original certificate folder `C:\Certbot\live\websiteurl`
- It doesn't let me undo, so I applied for another certificate, which was put in `C:\Certbot\live\websiteurl-0001`
- Deleted the original certificate folder and renamed the new folder as `C:\Certbot\live\websiteurl`

---

Errors that happened afterwards and what I did to resolve:

Tried to stop and restart Apache from XAMPP dashboard, but doesn't start (error log says: `script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat`)

- Changed `httpd.conf` 's `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`, and `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:8080`
- Changed `httpd-ssl.conf` 's `Listen 443` to `Listen 4433`, and `ServerName www.example.com:443` to `ServerName www.example.com:4433`
- Successfully started Apache

The website is still down, and the error log says `AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

- Changed `ServerName www.example.com:4433` to `ServerName url` (url is the domain of ssl certificate)
- The error doesn't appear anymore

Current situation: my website refused to connect, and the same for `localhost` and `127.0.01`

- Ping `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` all works correctly
- Tried turning off firewall, accessing `localhost:8080` (which doesn't work), changing port number of Apache web server (which is what I did above, which is changing `Listen 80`
  and `ServerName localhost:80` to 8080) solutions from https://appuals.com/localhost-refused-to-connect/

I have no idea what to do anymore, please help me fix it..
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem~ Here's what I did

- Uninstalled anti-virus software
- Changed back everything I changed in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf` file

So, I guess it was the anti-virus software messing around.